# show that finite orbit has a periodic point

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algebraic-topology, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

i am trying to prove that a finit orbit has a periodic point. The true statement of the exercise is:
"prove or disprove that if a point `x` has a finit orbit, then `x` is either a periodic point or a eventually periodic point."

Thank you very much

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: Could you add some more context? What are you looking at, a specific group $G$ acting on a set or a topological space $X$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much!!,

i use cycle detection. so i build this:

For a function `f` that map a finite set `S` to itself and a point `x0` in `S` and considering the sequence `x0, x1=f(x0), x2=f(x1),...,xn=f(x_n-1) for n>1`, eventually must be equal for any previous term in the sequence. Let `k` be the smallest index. Let `j<k` such that `xj=xk` then `xj` has an orbit of period `k-j`.

I am new here, so sorry i a make some mistakes in formats, etc...
Thank you very much!